# I need to provide rankings for 2 sets of values segmented by date

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns a table that has values for a number of given dates. I want to be able to know of any given set of results for each date, what is their rank. I cannot use a simple rank function as I need to do it for multiple columns, for multiple dates. Any suggestions of what function i need and how to write it?

Comment: Can you provide example tables / sql?

Comment: ^ and also your sorting rules. If there are multiple pieces of data involved in the sort, it cannot be a straightforward "`is x > y`" test.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, @rank := @rank + 1
from your_table, (select @rank := 0) r
```